# Rust - Enum method that calls method of inside values

Tags: rust, enums

I have an enum like follows:

```
enum Foo {
    A(X),
    B(Y),
    C(Z),
}
```

where X, Y, and Z are structs which implement the method `bar()`

I want to be able to define a method `bar` on the `Foo` enum so that it calls the corresponding method of its inside value. Right now I have this:

```
impl Foo {
    pub fn bar() {
        match self {
            Foo::A(f) => { f.bar(); }
            Foo::B(f) => { f.bar(); }
            Foo::C(f) => { f.bar(); }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do better than this using an enum, if possible?

Comment: This is already what you are suppose to do. if f type are the same you can do `Foo::A(f) | Foo::B(f) | Foo::C(f) => f.bar()` for example https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4f58a4d61c1e2939a7d970709505af62

Comment: The "problem" is I have 10 enum variants so the code got a little repetitive there, but doing that it will look a little cleaner, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using an enum, you could use a trait object:

```rust
trait Bar { fn bar(&self); }

struct X;
impl Bar for X { fn bar(&self) {} }


struct Y;
impl Bar for Y { fn bar(&self) {} }


struct Z;
impl Bar for Z { fn bar(&self) {} }

let mut x: Box<dyn Bar> = Box::new(X /* or Y or Z */);
x.bar();
```

However, this comes with the overhead of the `Box` and `dyn`amic dispatch. The code you have is the better solution. You can use the [`enum_dispatch`](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch) crate to remove some of the boilerplate if you prefer:

```rust
#[enum_dispatch]
trait Bar { fn bar(&self); }

#[enum_dispatch(Bar)]
enum Foo {
    A(X),
    B(Y),
    C(Z),
}

let foo = Foo::A(X);
foo.bar();
```

Comment: enum_dispatch doesn't "remove some boilerplate" it's doesn't use at all dynamic dispatch and should be the preferred solution if not done manually

Comment: I had tried trait objects but I needed to cast it to its concrete type later in the program so I ended up needing to implement `as_any` on all my types (around 10) so I decided to go with an enum instead.
I liked that `enum_dispatch` solution, thanks