# trait implementation with different parameter types

Tags: rust, traits

Is it possible to define a trait like the following one:

```rs
pub trait DataValidator {
  fn validate_data(&self, data: TBD) -> bool;
}
```

where the `TBD` type can be different data types like `u32`, `Vec<u8>`, `Vec<Vec<u8>>`, ... and have a different implementation for different enums that implement that trait?

The idea is to create a validator for different data types.
I have the following enum:

```rs
pub enum DataType {
  Text,
  Number,
  Array,
}
```

and I have an struct that uses that enum

```
pub struct Validator {
  pub data_type: DataType
}
```

I want to implement the trait for `Validator`, but the input that the `validate_data` function is not the same all the time, or at least that's what I want to cover.

So for example, let's say I have a Validator name `validator` with `data_type` set as `Text`. I want to then call the `validate_data` function like `validator.validate_data(data)` where data is a `Vec<u8>`. It only has to validate that the length of the `Vec` is within a certain limits.

But let's say I have another Validator named `validator2` with `data_type` set as `Array`. I want to pass to the `validate_data` function an array of different  `DataTypes` and validate each one of them using the same logic, but for that I need the trait to be flexible with the input type. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you would need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69670499/18244921)?

Comment: Although I've simplified here the example, I'm already working with structs within the enum, but the problem is that the trait itself receives an additional parameter that can be anything, so the problem here is how to set that `data`  input to any data type

Comment: I think you'd want to make the trait generic over the type its validating. Like `impl DataValidator<u32> for Validator` means that it can validate `u32`s and do that for all the types you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement dummy trait `SupportedDataType` just to indicate types that you support and connect each `DataValidator` trait with some type (`ValidatedDataType`) which will be trait `SupportedDataType` then you can change type for every implementation (which as I understood is required feature).

```rust
trait SupportedDataType {}

impl SupportedDataType for String {}

impl SupportedDataType for i32 {}

pub trait DataValidator {
    type ValidatedDataType: SupportedDataType;

    fn validate_data(&self, data: Self::ValidatedDataType) -> bool;
}

struct Validator {}

impl DataValidator for Validator {
    type ValidatedDataType = u64;

    fn validate_data(&self, data: Self::ValidatedDataType) -> bool {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In specific implementation you need to provide specific type.

Comment: It looks good to me! I’ll test it out and accept the answer asap